Sign-in with Apple Laravel 11 400 Bad Request response
I'm currently trying to implement 'Sign-in with Apple' connection in a  Laravel 11 project, but without Socialite. I am blocked with my callback method.
Here's the error that I get:

Client error: `POST https‍://appleid.apple.com/auth/token` resulted in a `400 Bad Request` response:{"error":"invalid_client","email_verified":false}

On the line:
$response = $client->post('https://appleid.apple.com/auth/token', [ 

Here's my controller:
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Models\User;
use GuzzleHttp\Client;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Laravel\Socialite\Facades\Socialite;
use Lcobucci\JWT\Configuration;
use Lcobucci\JWT\Signer\Key\InMemory;
use Lcobucci\JWT\Signer\Ecdsa\Sha256;

class AppleController extends Controller
{
    public function redirectToApple($slug, $number)
    {
        session(['slug' => $slug, 'number' => $number]);
        return Socialite::driver('apple')->redirect();
    }

    public function handleAppleCallback(Request $request)
    {
        $data = $request->all();

        $code = $data['code'];
        $state = $data['state'];

        if (empty($code)) {
            return response()->json(['error' => 'Authorization code not provided'], 400);
        }

        $clientId = env('APPLE_CLIENT_ID');
        $clientSecret = $this->generateClientSecret();
        $redirectUri = env('APPLE_REDIRECT_URI');

        $client = new Client();
        $response = $client->post('https://appleid.apple.com/auth/token', [
            'form_params' => [
                'grant_type' => 'authorization_code',
                'code' => $code,
                'redirect_uri' => $redirectUri,
                'client_id' => $clientId,
                'client_secret' => $clientSecret,
            ],
        ]);

        $tokens = json_decode($response->getBody(), true);

        if (isset($tokens['access_token'])) {
            $accessToken = $tokens['access_token'];
            $userData = $this->getUserData($accessToken);

            $existingUser = User::where('email', $userData['email'])->first();

            if ($existingUser) {
                Auth::login($existingUser);
            } else {
                $newUser = User::create([
                    'name' => $userData['name'],
                    'email' => $userData['email'],
                    'password' => bcrypt('default_password'),
                ]);

                Auth::login($newUser);
            }

            return redirect()->intended('/home');
        }

        return response()->json(['error' => 'Failed to obtain access token']);
    }

    public function generateClientSecret()
    {
        $privateKey = env('APPLE_PRIVATE_KEY');
        $config = Configuration::forSymmetricSigner(
            new Sha256(),
            InMemory::file($privateKey)
        );

        $now = new \DateTimeImmutable();
        $token = $config->builder()
            ->issuedBy(env('APPLE_TEAM_ID'))
            ->issuedAt($now)
            ->expiresAt($now->modify('+6 months'))
            ->relatedTo(env('APPLE_CLIENT_ID'))
            ->withClaim('sub', env('APPLE_CLIENT_ID'))
            ->getToken($config->signer(), $config->signingKey());

        return $token->toString();
    }
}

I already checked the .env data, I previously tried with Socialite, I found myself with a "400 bad request" error. I don't know what to do.

fyi questions need to be in English here. Please edit accordingly.

That error message seems to be indicating that your Apple developer account email hasn't been verified or similar

I believe the Apple developer account is verified because a mobile application has been published.
